Does anyone know a proof that these nested symmetric matrices are non singular?
Does anyone know where to find a proof that these nested symmetric matrices are non singular? Trivial for the first two, written below. But then?
$$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/3\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
$$ A_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\ 1/2 & 1/3 & 1/ 4 \\ 
                                                    1/3 & 1/4 & 1/5\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
.....
$$ A_P= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{ 1}{2} & \frac{ 1}{3}  & \cdots & \frac{ 1}{ P+1} \\ 
                          \frac{ 1}{ 2} & \frac{ 1^{\vphantom{P^-}}}{ 3} & \frac{ 1}{ 4} & \cdots&
                           \frac{ 1}{ P+2} \\ 
                          \frac{ 1}{ 3} & \frac{ 1^{\vphantom{P^-}}}{ 4} & \frac{ 1}{ 5} & \cdots&
                           \frac{ 1}{ P+2} \\
                           \vdots\\
                    \frac{ 1}{ P+1} & \frac{ 1}{ P+2} & \frac{ 1}{ P+3}  & \cdots &\frac{ 1}{ 2P+1}\end{pmatrix}$$

We have $$\det A_n =   {\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} k!^2 \over n^n \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (n^2-k^2)^{n-k}}$$ See the duplicate.

Thank you so much
